# Azure devops pipeline variable for a task step name

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a variable available for an Azure devops pipeline task step name, highlighted below?

pipeline image screenshot

[image: 1]

I've looked through the predefined variables at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic but none of them work/are suitable.

Comment: What have you tried so far? and what went wrong?

Comment: Try this : System.JobDisplayName

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the classic build pipeline, you can call the [build definition REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) to get the task steps names and then set the task names as pipeline variables using [logging commands - SetVariable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#setvariable-initialize-or-modify-the-value-of-a-variable). After that you can use the defined variables in the subsequent tasks in pipeline.

To do that by following below steps:

1.Enable the option "`Allow scripts to access OAuth token`" in Agent job. (Reference the following screenshot for the task steps involved in this sample)
[image]

2.Add a PowerShell task to set task step variables by running the
following script: (In this sample we defined the variable `taskcount` and `TaskStep$i`)

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/definitions/$env:SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID"
$result= Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}` 
$tasks = $result.process.phases.steps.displayName
$count = $tasks.count
    
# Set task count variable
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=taskcount]$count"
    
# Set task step variables
For($i=0;$i -lt $tasks.Length; $i++) {
  Write-host $($tasks[$i])
  Write-Host ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=TaskStep$i]$($tasks[$i])")
}
```

[image]

3.Add another PowerShell task and run below command to check the
defined `TaskStep` variables:

```
gci  env:* | Where-Object Name -like TaskStep* | sort-object name
```

[image]
[image]

4.Use the variables in the subsequent tasks in pipeline. Print variable value for example using PowerShell task:

```
Write-Host "TaskCount:" $(taskcount)
Write-Host "TaskStep0:" $(TASKSTEP0)
Write-Host "TaskStep1:" $(TASKSTEP1)
Write-Host "TaskStep2:" $(TASKSTEP2)
Write-Host "TaskStep3:" $(TaskStep3)
Write-Host "TaskStep4:" $(TaskStep4)
Write-Host "TaskStep5:" $(TaskStep5)
Write-Host "TaskStep6:" $(TaskStep6)
Write-Host "TaskStep7:" $(TaskStep7)
Write-Host "TaskStep8:" $(TaskStep8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you want to use Pipeline variable to set the Task Group name.

I am afraid that there is no such pipeline variable can achieve this requirement.

The Pipeline variable will only be expanded when the pipeline is running. Then the pipeline variable will update the task name.

When you set a variable in the task definition, it cannot be expanded directly.

The workaround is that you can hardcode the task name in task definition. In this case, it will show the expected task name.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)

Comment: Agree with this answer... but dynamic names would be a big help. We have one build that loops over a template 20+ times.. would be nice to include the name of the parameter value in the display names of the steps.... (I can provide an example if not understood)